# How can I omit downloading default themes in drupal core in make file

Tags: drush

Is it possible to not download the default themes- e.g. bartik, garland etc, in my make file when I download the drupal core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I do not believe a makefile (assuming you mean Drush Make) can do this.  Deleting the actual theme files is not the best approach, since each time core is updated they will be re-downloaded.

If you want to remove core themes from the Appearance admin section, you can hide them with [hook_system_info_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_system_info_alter/7)().

```
function example_system_info_alter(&$info, $file, $type) {
  if ($type == 'theme' && $info['name'] == 'Bartik') {
    $info['hidden'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```